# Android: Show Dialog in SearchDialog Activity

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to show a Dialog or AlertDialog that is launched by the Search Activity that is set as the default search activity?
I have a SearchDialog that is working as intended but i want to show a dialog with extra search option each time a search is executed.
It wont work by simply implementing the dialog in the Search Activity that is called by my view activities...
Does anyone have an idea?